# How to simple edit local config file throuth API

Tags: node.js, https, server, devops

In all servers we got some .env files, which sets configs for server (Node.JS) on start.

Now I want to edit this files from admin pane (another web-service, working with main server through API). 
Is there any best practices or just good ideas how can I realize that?

First idea - create another web-server on instance, which will have only two API endpoints (read, write) and which will restart server after editing configs. This idea looking too heavy.

Second idea is to create bash script, which will send requests to admin servers to take actual configs and rewrite local .env file if find some changes, but here will be a lot unnecessary requests. (Request every minute, but configs will change 1 time per month).

What do you think? Any ideas?

Comment: If I were you, I would go for the first idea.

Comment: @Eitank 
1) all developers in company have access to git, but only chosens have access to servers. 
2) Git is still foreign servers, and I don't want sensitive data on a foreign server.

Why configs in git repo more secure then?

Comment: @BorisPaschenko,
1. about the access to git you can create a team in github and authorise them only to this repository.
2. http can have vulnerabilities and deploying through jenkins or whatever can have a better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options and it depends primarily on your deployment strategy..

If you have a distributed environment and/or your configuration changes often (i.e.: running multiple docker containers, rotating keys, etc.) I'd highly recommend using a K/V store and reading configuration(s) dynamically during application start. Check out HashiCorp Vault, etcd or even mongodb.

If your configuration contains sensitive data definitely use something like HashiCorp Vault. If you use a configuration tool like ansible, it has `ansible-vault` which will encrypt your secret(s) at rest and decrypt them during deployment.

I would highly advise against storing (even potentially) sensitive data such as api keys, tokens, etc. in version control. This is a pretty big attack vector and will lead you down a dark road.

Worst case scenario use environment variables. Almost all CI/CD tooling supports these and you can maintain separation of concerns.